# can't start smtp debug sever in windows cmd line

Tags: python

I downloaded and installed Python. It is added to envoirment variable Path. And I can run it in cmd line:

```
Python 3.12.1 (tags/v3.12.1:2305ca5, Dec  7 2023, 22:03:25) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hello")
hello
```

But when I tried to start smtp debug server, it shows error: No module named smtpd

Why I couldn't run it? What did I do wrong?

```
C:\Users\ad>python -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -n 127.0.0.1:1025
C:\Users\ad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe: No module named smtpd
```

Comment: `smtpd` was removed in Python 3.12, see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.12.html#smtpd